# PostgreSQL Peer Authentication User Mapping Failed

Tags: postgresql

Logged in to the server as user root, I need to enter a database as user postgres via Unix socket. This is my pg_ident.conf:

```
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
testmap         postgres                postgres
testmap         root                    postgres
```

This is my pg_hba.conf:

```
# TYPE   DATABASE   USER   ADDRESS   METHOD
local    all        all              peer map=testmap
```

I already did pg_ctl reload, even restarted the postgresql service and the server itself. I'm getting the following when connecting via psql:

```
[root@<Server> ~]# psql -d postgres
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "root", database "postgres", SSL off
```

Checked hba_file and ident_file inside the database and can confirm that the locations I'm editing are the correct ones.

Are there any other configurations I'm missing? Do I have to create role/user root in the database?

I've been looking for similar problems here and in stackoverflow for 2 days now and most of them just forgot to include map=<> in pg_hba.conf. I also believe what I did was in line with the instructions in the PostgreSQL manual.

Btw, I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5.12. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today and it turns out that Postgres will actually try to assume the role passed with the `-U` parameter. What worked for me was this:

```
# psql -U postgres -d postgres
```

Then, the authentication will use your socket peer username (`root`), but you will become `postgres` upon authenticating. I'm not sure why Postgres does not map the user on its own - this is probably a documentation issue rather than a bug.